# What type of connector is this? Looks like a kind of shrouded EIAJ

Tags: identification, connector, plug

This type of connector is used in some OMRON TENS devices and I'd like to know which kind of connector is this. If you have the reference or a way to get the female connector, it would be really helpful.

[image: OMRON Pocket Pain Pro Connector]

Comment: For component identification questions, you need dimensions of the part, please find them and edit your question

Answer (score 0):

seen the applied product I guess this are custom made connectors and therefore not for sale because the profits of this manufacturer are made by the selling of the accesories.